# Find the vector having for image (1,1,1) by T

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

**Question: Find the vector having for image (1,1,1) by T**

$$T(x,y,z) = (y,6y,x+y+z)$$

I found the **standard matrix** to be:

\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&6&0\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}

and T(1,1,1) = $$T(1,1,1) = (1,6,3)$$

I'm confused on how to approach this question.

- In order to find the vector is it possible to inverse the values of it's standard matrix?

Any help/tips will be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:** this is not a duplicate, as the question states to find the **vector**, while the other question was to find the image.

Comment: To be clear, you want $(x,y,z)$ st $(y,6y,x+y+z)=(1,1,1)$? Well that is not possible because that would require $y=1$ and $6y=1$.

Comment: If you are *not* interested in the image of the vector $(1,1,1)$, why did you compute it then?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I just wanted to provide as much information possible, as I thought it would help solve it?

Comment: Also, to answer your dotted question, no you cannot invert this matrix since it has two columns that are clearly linearly dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with your previous question concerning this linear transformation, the matrix is useless. You just solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}y=1\\6y=1\\x+y+z=1.\end{array}\right.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: I see that y =1 but also y = 1/6, this is the part that confuses me. Since y cannot be 1 & 1/6

Comment: Sure. Therefore, the system has no solution. And therefore there is no vector $(x,y,z)$ such that $T(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)$.